# What's the cheapest way to destroy a hostile laser tower?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

In the treasure map quest, the player has to destroy a set of laser towers.

The only problem is that they more powerful and longer range than my own lasers. Also the tenacious towers can apparently shoot down longer range missiles (I learned to my dismay), as well as possessing powerful shields.

What's the best way to take these things out?

My current plan is to save up for some exotic expensive long range laser or ammunition weapon but I'm not sure which one.  My backup plan is to buy a huge warship and outgun them at close range using an array of expensive shields.

Still, I'm not sure what's the most efficient way to spend money to overcome this obstacle.

What's the cheapest way to take out a set of hostile laser towers with a range of, at least, 5km and fairly powerful shields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distract the laser towers.  Overwhelm them with a bunch of swarm missiles, wasps work great in that regard, and then sneak in a slower missile with a big punch.  This tactic is pretty great overall whenever you use missiles.  Wasps are one of my favorite missiles for distraction due to its relatively high speed and the swarm capability.  Not to mention they can be 'shotgunned' at nearby m5 and m4s to take them out fast.

If you are in a M6 or higher, you can pretty much ignore the return fire and take it out fairly fast.

Answer (score 4):

If you go real close, the turret will rotate to your direction slower then you can move.
Just shot it with my sabre taking only a single hit from the tower, while moving closer. 
Was strafing around it in a less than 100m distance at low speed (50-70).

Comment: This worked for me to take out the towers near a Pirate Base in a Nova.  Worth noting that you can use the station's shadow to get in close.

Answer (score 2):

You could attack with more ships, and it would be better if most of them are >= M3 (with strong shields). The turret is only able to fire at one ship at a time, and the others then may take it out.

You could also use cover to get some rest if your shields are depleted. Most times that I've encountered laser towers they protected stations or were even located near asteroid fields (if they protected pirate bases).